# Symfony Warning : rename (../app/cache/dev , ../app/cache/dev_old ) : Access Denied . (Code : 5)

Tags: symfony

I am working on Symfony project.

When i try to do :

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

i get the following ErrorException:

```
Warning : rename (../app/cache/dev , ../app/cache/dev_old ) : Access Denied . (Code : 5) in ../vendors/Symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php on line 76
```

What is the problem here? I have given all permissions to the user on my machine (Windows 7 OS). Any ideas why it is happening?

Thank You.

Comment: Sometimes it happens when the cache files are in use. Are you able to remove the cache folder manually?

Comment: No i din't try to remove them manually. Should i do that?

Comment: I usually write my own script which just empties out the cache folder, I find it works better than the built in `cache:clear`

Comment: Deleting the cache folder manually solved it for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be sure that the files are not in use (as [meze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062365/symfony-warning-rename-app-cache-dev-app-cache-dev-old-access-den#comment11373195_9062365) pointed out). If you're using something like TortoiseGit or Netbeans, etc - be sure to mark the `cache` folder as ignored so that they are not accessed.

If all else fails, download a free program like [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) that will allow you to quickly and easily detach running processes from the files/folders you are trying to modify.

Comment: closing any IDE, restart local server(wamp for me), running "php composer.phar update" and it's working and resolve my problem

Comment: 2 years later->still useful.

Comment: Remove the link to that unlocker thing. It installed 15 crapware and toolbars, and messed up a bunch of file associations. Took me nearly an hour just to fix the damage. Scanning my comp to make sure it didn't also sneak in a few viruses.

Comment: @afilina: The toolbar is optional; you must do a customized/advanced installation and decline its installation.

Comment: Great! 2017 and still working! I use Sublime Text, and to exclude folders on project check this: https://coderwall.com/p/dza-mw/exclude-files-folders-in-sublime-text

Answer (score 6):

To expand on leek's post, Symfony 2 cache-clearing operations shuffle the cached items across different folders during the cleanup.  Part of this process includes creating cache/dev-new/ and cache/dev-old/ folders.

If you are using Eclipse or another IDE that dynamically monitors subfolders within your project, the IDE will nearly instantly spot the new folder creation and look in those folders for new files (in Eclipse, I noticed the DLTK module constantly doing this in the Progress View).  This may unfortunately get in the way of Symfony, which wants to rename and/or delete these folders.

Specifically with Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7 64-bit, you can remove the cache/, cache/dev/, cache/dev_old/ and cache/dev_new/ folders from the build path by right-clicking your project and selecting "Build Path > Configure Build Path...".  This originally had no effect for me; I kept seeing the DLTK module trying to index the cache folders. I ended up uninstalling the Aptana Studio plug-in, closing all Editor documents, shutting down Eclipse, manually deleting the sub-folders in the cache/ folder, running Symfony cache:clear, then starting up Eclipse and reinstalling Aptana.  Seems to have worked thus far.

Answer (score 5):

It's an issue with Symfony 2.0.x and Symfony 2.1.x. These a [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/9NFunxsDTnQ) for this:

Open the file: `src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand.php`

and add the statement `sleep(1);` where the directory creation is failing, in the `execute()` function:

```
    //...
    rename($realCacheDir, $oldCacheDir);
    sleep(1);
    rename($warmupDir, $realCacheDir);
    //...
```

You might have to re-open the CLI twice and run `cache:clear`, but it will fix the problem after that

Comment: closing any IDE, restart local server(wamp for me), running "php composer.phar update" and it's working and resolve my problem

Comment: You should not edit the vendor file itself. every time you installed the library, you will have your change overridden.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using text editors as Sublime Text try to ignore path of cached files

Go to Preferences/Setting

edit config file

```
{
...
     "folder_exclude_patterns": ["var","node_modules",  ".git"],
...
}
```

in my case

Cache folders containers.

Symfony 4

/var

Symfony 2

/app/cache

Nice coding!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Symfony 4.1.13 and the root cause was that the VS Code was using the file "var/cache/dev/srcDevDebugProjectContainer.xml4QSKuA".

The issue was  Cannot rename  "var/cache/dev/srcDevDebugProjectContainer.xml4QSKuA".

I fix it adding **/var on the fields "Files to Exclude"

See the following steps:

1º Step:

[image: Firs Step]

2º Step search for "exclude" word, then add **/var/cache as the following image:

[image: Second Step]

It's worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Caique... For me it worked just by adding the folder in the "Watcher Exclude" configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To have tranquility once and for all I create **clear.bat** file in MyProject folder under Windows 7 .

```
rmdir d:\symfony\framework-standard-edition\app\cache\  /S /Q
```

I guarantee 100% effectiveness for cleaning cache. Some minor problems can occurred after first time refresh website: Symfony must recreate some folders they need.

Answer (score -1):

SYMFONY AND ANTIVIRUS

Multiple symfony calling in local windows machine get cross with some Antivirus software such as NOD in my case. Exclude symfony cache folder from real time protection