# "Access denied" error on 'rename' call when uploading files in Symfony

Tags: file-upload, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony project in a Win7/Apache 2.2/ZendStudio environment and I have some trouble getting my file uploads to work properly.

My goal is to let the user create a new entity which can contain arbitrary many "Documents" (based on the article found at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html). I have a form type containing one field of type 'collection' (based on the article found at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). So far so good. Via jQuery I can add arbitrarily many forms as subforms which works fine. But when I submit my form, very often (but not always!) I get the following exception:

`Warning: rename(C:/Programming/Servers/Apache2.2/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__MyMainBundleEntityRecruiter.php.507bf02e30df69.85090364,C:/Programming/Servers/Apache2.2/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__MyMainBundleEntityLecture.php): Zugriff verweigert (code: 5) in C:\Programming\Servers\Apache2.2\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php line 194`

*Zugriff verweigert* is German for *Access denied*. Weirdly, the files seem to get renamed and saved at the right location nevertheless.

Why do I get this exception, does it have something to do with my environment and how can I fix it? I guess this issue is related to [Symfony Warning : rename (../app/cache/dev , ../app/cache/dev_old ) : Access Denied . (Code : 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062365/symfony-warning-rename-app-cache-dev-app-cache-dev-old-access-den), but not quite sure whether it's the same as it happens in another context. I do also encounter the problem described in this link, though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this while looking for same answer, it seems to be a windows + Doctrine issue.

[Doctrine Ticket with more detailed info](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/2907)

TLDR: Basically the proxy is trying to rename a file that's still being used, works in Linux but not always on windows.

Comment: Anyone with ideas of resolutions? I've seen on this post that it's fixed in Doctrine 2.5, but as I run it (on Symfony 2.6.1) I still get the error. Maybe update the Symfony, or what?

Comment: Agreed. It says fixed 2.5 but I am still getting this on Doctrine 2.5.4 in XAMPP & Windows 10 x64 ... :(

Comment: Downvoting since the link is not online anymore. The answer should be completely on SO.

Comment: Link is broken :/

Answer (score 7):

I've been running into the same exact issue recently. I don't really have a good sense of why the problem is happening, but the problem is coming from a step in the process where Doctrine is trying to generate proxy classes.

In my config.yml file, under the ORM section of the Doctrine configuration, I changed the value of `auto_generate_proxy_classes` from `%kernel.debug%` to `false`. I've played with it for a while since making the change and haven't been able to reproduce the issue since.

Comment: Be careful! The documentation clearly warns about that: "When you do this in a development environment, be aware that you may get class/file not found errors if certain proxies are not yet generated."  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/advanced-configuration.html#auto-generating-proxy-classes-optional

Answer (score 1):

Go to the file that renames the file, then replace it with a windows compatible rename function

```
private function renameWindowsCompatible($oldfile,$newfile) {
    try {
        rename($oldfile,$newfile);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        if (copy($oldfile,$newfile)) {
            unlink($oldfile);
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This is just a temporary fix for the vendor, I don't know if doctrine will consider this update soon

Answer (score 0):

I learned about proxies and saw that it is used with lazy loading.
I had an entity A with a one to one relationship to B.
B was the problem is the proxies directory
I just had fetch="EAGER" annotation in A entity

> /**
>
> - @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=B::class, fetch="EAGER")
>   */
>   private $b;

Then the B proxy was not generated and no more problem with rename.

Hope this help.