# "Access Denied Code 5" PHP Rename Error in Symfony2/Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am getting the infamous Doctrine "PHP Rename Access Denied Code 5" error in my Symfony2 project when logging in using the User entity:

```
\\app\\cache\\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\\__CG__AcmeDemoBundleEntityUser.php): Access is denied. (code: 5)
```

I will log in OK, and if I am lucky, I can load a page before the session is killed as a result of the user authentication failing as a result of this error.  It only happens with this one entity.

My colleague, with the same set up and same project has the same error but for a different entity (and ONLY that entity).

This problem has been reported [on here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894822/access-denied-error-on-rename-call-when-uploading-files-in-symfony), with a link to the bug on [Doctrine's GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2907) which was confirmed fixed as of 2.5 (confirmed in [Doctrine ORM 2.5 Release Notes](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2015/04/02/orm-2-5-0.html)).

My Symfony2 project is running with Doctrine ORM 2.5.4 yet I am still getting the same error.

**Attempted Fixes**

- Reinstall XAMPP;
- Deleted project & pulled project from git;
- Updated vendor projects (maybe an old Doctrine ORM package remained);
- Closing PHPStorm (maybe it's locking the files for indexing);
- Disabled Windows indexing (same reason as above).

Changing the value of `auto_generate_proxy_classes` from `%kernel.debug%` to `false` in config_dev.yml prevents the problem, but this *hides* the issue instead of fixing it.

Has anyone managed to actually fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set up `auto_generate_proxy_classes` to a underlying constant value for [AbstractProxyFactory::AUTOGENERATE_EVAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.5/class-Doctrine.Common.Proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.html#AUTOGENERATE_EVAL) or [AbstractProxyFactory::AUTOGENERATE_FILE_NOT_EXISTS](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.5/class-Doctrine.Common.Proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.html#AUTOGENERATE_FILE_NOT_EXISTS).

According to this documentation section [Advanced Configuration > Auto-generating Proxy Classes](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#auto-generating-proxy-classes-optional) this should fix the access denied problem in development environment.

Also, you should make sure your production configuration follows this recommendation:

> In a production environment, it is highly recommended to use AUTOGENERATE_NEVER to allow for optimal performances. The other options are interesting in development environment.